# How to use Python to get elements that do not appear in HTML, but appear in "Inspect Element" tool of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, html, geoip, maxmind

Dear Python Experts out there!
I am totally new to Python and writing a small program to fetch the information from a web page. There is nothing to ask if the page would return all the information in the page-source HTML, which can easily view by Chrome. The problem is that the Elements I want to get after submitting an IP address to https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo do not appear in the body of HTML, but only when I click "inspect element" tool of Chrome. I used to following code to post to the page and print the response string, but the elements I want are not there.

```
import urllib2
import requests

url = 'https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo'
data = {'addresses':'162.237.72.200'}

post = requests.post(url, data = data)
content = post.content

print content
```

With this code, I hope to get some information related to the IP address in the body of HTML such as

```
162.237.72.200  
US  
Pittsburg,California,United States,North America    
94565   
38.0051,
-121.8387   
AT&T U-verse    
AT&T U-verse    
sbcglobal.net   
807
```

But those information is not there in the HTML body, so I am really grateful if anyone could give me just a hint to solve the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: While inspecting the page in Firefox, I see that a GET request gets sent to "`https://www.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/your.ip.here`" when you click "submit". Maybe you could query that page directly instead of the "geoip-demo" page.

Comment: Thanks Kenvin for promptly pointing out the internal link, but When I try it, the page request UserName and PassWord. While inputting directly to the "geoip-demo" page, it provides the information for free, and doesn't ask for membership account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution simulating the browser navigation and interaction with the form to retrieve the data using scrapy and webdriver.

```
class MaxSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "max"
    allowed_domains = ["maxmind.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo"]

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('addresses')
    login_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('addresses')
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.click(login_form)
    actions.perform()
    login_form.send_keys("62.237.72.200")
    submit = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="geoip-demo-form"]/button')
    actions.click(submit)
    time.sleep(3)
    for element in self.driver.find_elements_by_id('geoip-demo-results-tbody'):
       print element.text
    self.driver.close()
```

**excerpt from output:**

> 2015-01-13 13:27:18+0100 [max] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo> (referer: http://www.bing.com)
>
> 62.237.72.200 FI Finland, Europe 60.1708,
>   24.9375 Tele Danmark Tele Danmark